# user agent stylesheet (Chrome) in body

Tags: php, css, google-chrome, stylesheet

I have the problem, that Chrome adds a user agent stylesheet on my body, so that the body is bigger than I defined in the Css...

I read a lot about the user agent stylesheet, but I couldn't find a solution, which overwrites the body user agent stylesheet with my actual Css code...

Chrome adds that text to it and when i delete it it is just like I wanted the website to be... (but when I refresh it is of course like before)
- you can see it in the picture...

[Where the red cross is should be no text... then it would work...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng2I0.png)

```css
html{
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
body {
 background-color: #BDBDBD;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: AcmeFont, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
 text-align: left; 
}

.BODY{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width:70%;
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  
<head>
    <title>Website Title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" >
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body class="BODY">
</body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a library like [normalize](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Comment: I tryed to do that, but the user agent is still there... But why does Chrome make a user agent on a page, but on a exactly same not...? : (